# understanding basic Laplace transformation

Tags: laplace-transform

I am trying to understand Laplace transformations.
Could someone tell me from where the fraction (1/-s), in red on the first line is originated?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xksa3.jpg

Comment: You might be interested to [post mathematical expressions](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) using MathJax and $\LaTeX$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\color{red}{\left(\dfrac{1}{-s}\right)}$ comes because you do  $dt\color{red}{(-s)}$

[image: you mistaken $1$ for $s$]
You change one $1$ for and $s$ accidentally

**edit** other way: since $\left(\dfrac{e^{-st}}{-s}\right)'=e^{-st}$ then $\mathcal{L\{1\}}=\displaystyle\lim_{b\to\infty} \left( \dfrac{e^{-sb}}{-s}-\dfrac{e^{-s.0}}{-s} \right)$

Comment: Why do you need to add this?

Comment: If you see your resolución, you can solve the integral by differents ways, but the indication in your paper shows that you solve the integral by change of variable $t\mapsto t'(-s):=-st$ so $dt=(-sd)t'=-sdt $ Is clear now?

Comment: No, it is not clear from why you need to add the .(-s) at the end and why you add the fraction in the beginning. I see the logic more or less but don't understand the reason

Comment: @privetDruzia and now?

Comment: Thanks, clearer. But what is the reason of the second line? Why do you bring the s down? Is there a reason or is it just part of the algorithm?

Comment: @privetDruzia I bring $s$ down because I'm using a trick to solve easiest the integral, I do $u=-st$ and I want to change $dt$ for $du$ but $du=-sdt$ so I need an $(-s)$ in the numerator, so I multiply for $\frac{-s}{-s}$  so $s\neq0$ then I do the antiderivate and then return $u$ to $-st$.

Comment: @privetDruzia I've improved my answer, please read it.

Answer (score 0):

the neutral factor $\frac{-s}{-s}$ has simply be introduced, then one part kept in the integral and the other out...

Comment: Why is it introduced?